# Include only complete groups in panel regression using Stata

Tags: panel, stata

I have a panel set of data but not all individuals are present for all periods. I see when I run my `xtreg` that there are between 1-4 observations per group with a mean of 1.9. I'd like to only include those with 4 observations. Is there any way I can do this easily?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to include in your regression only those groups for which there are exactly 4 observations. If this is the case, then one solution is to count the number of observations per group and condition the regression using `if`:

```
clear all
set more off

webuse nlswork
xtset idcode

list idcode year in 1/50, sepby(idcode)

bysort idcode: gen counter = _N

xtreg ln_w grade age c.age#c.age ttl_exp c.ttl_exp#c.ttl_exp tenure ///
    c.tenure#c.tenure 2.race not_smsa south if counter == 12, be
```

In this example the regression is conditioned to groups with 12 observations. The `xtreg` command gives (among other things):

> Number of obs = 1881
>
> Number of groups = 158

which you can compare with the result of running the regression without the `if`:

> Number of obs = 28091
>
> Number of groups = 4697

As commented by @NickCox, if you don't mind losing observations you can `drop` or `keep` (un)desired groups:

```
bysort idcode: drop if _N != 4
```

or

```
bysort idcode: keep if _N == 4
```

followed by an unconditional `xtreg` (i.e. with no `if`).

Notice that both approaches count missings, so you may need to account for that.

On the other hand, you might want to think about why you want to discard that data in your analysis.

Comment: A one-liner is to `drop` panels that don't come up to scratch or to `keep` those that do. In the simplest case this would be something like `bysort panelid: keep if _N == 4`. Missing values need extra care and extra code.